# Targeting Apple devices with 2.6 dppx through media queries

Tags: ios, web-applications, apple-touch-icon

All Apple modern devices use either a 2 or 3 dppx resolution, except for the iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, and iPhone 6s Plus, which use a 2.6 dppx resolution.

I'm trying to target those devices to add a Splash Screen for my web app... but I'm trying to figure out if both of these alternatives would be valid:

**Option A**

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-resolution: 3dppx) and (width: 414px) and (height: 736px)" href="apple-launch-1080x1920.png">
```

**Option B**

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(resolution: 2.6dppx) and (width: 414px) and (height: 736px)" href="apple-launch-1080x1920.png">
```

I prefer option B but I don't know if using a non-integer value for the resolution property is actually valid.